C++ Templates for inheritance - How to use constructor?
I'm working on a C++ project where I use templates to easily switch between implementations of several inherited classes.
Combined with ceres solver, I've come across this situation where I need to create an object of the template type, however this isn't possible due to an error:

C2665 - no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

Is there a workaround to create an object of the templated type?
Edit: Thank you for your quick replies. Here is the revised working example that should now reproduce my problem though it doesn't do much and make much sense. The inheritance doesn't seem to play a role here but is the reason for templating in the first place.
Please, note that I am restricted to have the method template<typename T> bool operator()(...) const otherwise I cannot interact with ceres:
#define GLOG_NO_ABBREVIATED_SEVERITIES
#define NOMINMAX
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) //Windows compiler specific with Ceres version 2.1.0
#include <ceres/ceres.h>


template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        X = static_cast<T>(0.0);
        Y = static_cast<T>(0.0);
    }
    Base(const T* io_array)
    {
        this->X = io_array[0];
        this->Y = io_array[1];
    }
    T doMath()
    {
        return X * X + Y * Y;
    }
protected:
    T X, Y;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
    Derived() : Base()
    {
        Z = static_cast<T>(0.0);
    }
    Derived(const T* io_array) : Base<T>(io_array)
    {
        this->Z = io_array[2];
    }
    T doMath()
    {
        return this->X * this->X + this->Y * this->Y + this->Z * this->Z;
    }
protected:
    T Z;
};

template<typename IO>
struct cRelOri {
    cRelOri(const double var)
    {
        this->var = var;
    }
        template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* const io_array, T* residual) const
    {
        IO io(io_array); //Error C2665
        T res = io.doMath();

        //This works:
        //Base<T> io(io_array);
        //T res = io.doMath();

        //This also works:
        //Derived<T> io(io_array);
        //T res = io.doMath();
        residual[0] = res;
        
        return true;
    }

private:
    double var;
public:
    static ceres::CostFunction* Create(double& var1) {
        return (new ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<cRelOri, 1, 3>
            (new cRelOri(var1)));
    }
};



int main()
{
    double io_array[3] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
    double var = 4.2;
    // Create problem
    ceres::Problem problem;
    ceres::CostFunction* cost_function_ro = cRelOri<Derived<double>>::Create(var);
    problem.AddResidualBlock(cost_function_ro, NULL, io_array);
    
    ceres::Solver::Options options;
    ceres::Solver::Summary summary;
    ceres::Solve(options, &problem, &summary);

    return 0;
}

I've tried using pointers of a base class and then dynamic_cast'ing them to IO, which doesn't throw an error directly, but then strangely cannot convert identical (template) types any more to use the pointer.

Please [edit] your question with an [mre] or SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Welcome to StackOverflow! Let's take it one step at a time. "Is there a workaround to create an object of the templated type?". No! There is no workaround. You instantiate a templated object, just like you instantiate any other object type. There are no workarounds. Error C2665 is the same as in any other situation, even if that object wasn't templated you'd still get it. And as a minor caveat, don't abuse this->member so much. It's not needed (unless there's ambiguity).

Now, onwards to your issue. Your cast operator bool operator()(const T* const io_array, T* residual) const. is your issue. You're trying a const T* const from cRelOri to a const T* inside Base. BTW, you are showing us the templates, but not showing us any instantiation or specialization. Please update the code inside the question.

Your Derived template constructor is bugged as tries to construct Base<T> via default constructor while Base<T> doesn't have it as a custom constructor is declared.

Also, what is static_cast<T>(0.0) supposed to do? Is T a double? long? It is always initialized with a double value. So is it any numeric type?

T is both a double and Jet type (dual number for automatic differentiation in Ceres. Code is supposed to work with double. I've casted the double just for safety as I ran into problems with that earlier in other cases.

OK, got it. Please update the code to see where operator() is called or used.

The problem here is that Ceres calls the operator() function under the radar when ceres::Solve is called, so there is not really anything to add without writing larger parts of the library itself, I guess. However, for completeness, I've added the call to the solver to run the optimization.
